# Count occurrences of values in 1 column based on index from where condition in different columns is True

Tags: python, numpy

I have data in 4 columns that looks like this:

```
day month year value
 1    1   1880  1
Etc. for each day in a month for each month for 1880-2013.
Values range from 1 to 8
```

The data is stored

I want to count how many times each "value" occurs in for a given month and year. So something like this:

```
data = np.loadtxt('/path/to/file', skiprows=1)

def magic_func(data,year,month):
for each in zip(data[:,1], data[:,2]):
    if each == (month,year):
        #actual magic
```

E.g. output:

```
[(1,0), (2,30), (3,0), (4,0), (5,1), (6,0), (7,0), (8,0)]
```

So I figure I need a way to index the last column of **data** based on the index where the **if** above is True and then count (probably np.bincount?) how many times each "value" occurs. I've not made much progress in terms of code though...

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** I wasn't keen on posting any real data as even for 1 year that's 365 data points! The data is stored in a .txt file delimited by tabs but I can store it as csv as well. A (very small) sample is below. Didn't entirely preserve the proper tabs when copied in though, the actual file obviously has each column under the appropriate name...What I originally did is copied the data form somewhere else and used Excel's Text to Columns to create my .txt.

```
day     month   year    value
1   1   1956    3
2   1   1956    3
3   1   1956    8
4   1   1956    8
5   1   1956    8
6   1   1956    3
7   1   1956    1
8   1   1956    1
9   1   1956    3
10  1   1956    3
11  1   1956    3
12  1   1956    3
13  1   1956    1
14  1   1956    1
15  1   1956    3
16  1   1956    2
17  1   1956    3
18  1   1956    3
19  1   1956    3
20  1   1956    3
21  1   1956    3
22  1   1956    3
23  1   1956    3
24  1   1956    3
25  1   1956    1
26  1   1956    7
27  1   1956    4
28  1   1956    4
29  1   1956    4
30  1   1956    1
31  1   1956    1
```

What I want is for all items under "value" where "month" is e.g. 1 in this case to count how many times each unique "value" occurs. In this particular case the output'd be:

```
[(3,16), (8,3), (1,7), (2,1), (7,1), (4,3)] # format is (value, count)
# or if displaying all possible values
[(1,7), (2,1), (3,16), (4,3), (5,0), (6,0), (7,1), (8,3)]
```

Does that make sense?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure that it should be `(4,1)` and not `(4,3)`? There /are/ 3 occurrences of `4` in the first month of 1956

Comment: Ah yes, my fault, you do understand what my aim is though it would seem :).

Comment: In that case, my answer should get you through

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import collections

def count(infilepath):
    answer = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(int)))
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        infile.readline()
        for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
            *_rest, month, year, value = [int(i) for i in line]
            answer[year][month][value] += 1
    return answer
```

Usage:

```
counts = count('/path/to/input')
for year in sorted(counts):
    yeard = counts[year]
    for month in sorted(yeard):
        monthd = yeard[month]
        for day in sorted(monthd):
            occ = monthd[day]
            print("In year %d, in month %d, there were %d occurrences of day %d" %(year, month, val, day))
```

Comment: I've added some example data.